# issue to Export to Excel from datagrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, export-to-excel

I bind a paged collection view to datagrid. When I export to Excel that datagrid, it only exports visible page's data, not all Item source (all records).

ex- my code-

```
 PagedCollectionView page = new PagedCollectionView(_leads);
 Pager.Source = page;
 datagrid.ItemsSource = page;
```

When I did export to Excel it only export the records from the one at a time which is visible. I want to export all.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a code sample in the top-voted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304322/silverlight-datagrid-export-to-excel-or-csv) that deals with exporting a DataGrid to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Town for the reply .. I got the solution actually my Item source is of Paged collection view .. 
and In Export to excel I used ..

```
PagedCollectionView source = (grid.ItemsSource as PagedCollectionView);
source.SourceCollection;
```

which return me all records and not only from visible page ..and problem is solved
thanks again