# Export Datagrid to csv when using datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, datagrid, export

My xaml looks like this:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dg_Ingaven" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>   
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    ...
```

I need to convert the datagrid to an csv file I found alot of solutions if Datagrid is AutoGenerateColumns = "true" but how do I make it work with datagridcolumns with a textblock inside?

this is the solution I found: [Silverlight DataGrid: Export to excel or csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304322/silverlight-datagrid-export-to-excel-or-csv)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved it by using [`DataGridTextColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!

Comment: If you want to help future visitors, add a more detailed explanation and accept your answer by ticking the green checkmark. Cheers.